# Why link:visited property doesn't work (for page link)?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have linked between different pages. Now I want that if a visitor visits any page by clicking on the link, that link will changed into different colors.

In my case it's not working, I don't know why.

My code:

HTML:

```
    <div id="pageLink">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php" id="index"><div id="indexDiv">Welcome</div></a></li>
<li><a href="about-me.php" id="aboutMe"><div id="aboutMeDiv">Bio</div></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #index,#aboutMe{
text-decoration:none;

}
#index:visited,#aboutMe:visited{
color:red;
}
#indexDiv,#aboutMeDiv {
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
padding:5px;
color:green;
font-family:Tahoma;
font-size:20px;
}
#indexDiv:hover,#aboutMeDiv:hover{
color:gray;
}
#pageLink li{
        display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
}
```

Here is the [Live](https://jsfiddle.net/dotczmga/)

Comment: Don't assign colors to #indexDiv and #aboutMeDiv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are having a `div` inside `a` anchor tag with style `color:green;`

change the css snippet as

```
#index:visited > div,
#aboutMe:visited > div {
  color:red;
}
```

you will get red color when the anchor tag has `:visited` pseudo class.